# How to search for substring in a pandas column from a given list efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I search for substring in a column efficiently?  If I use str.contains() method, it takes forever to search through the df.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['111,222,333,444', '11,44', '222,333,444','666,777','555']})
mylist = ['111', '222', '444','555']
pattern = '|'.join(mylist)
frame.loc[frame.a.str.contains(pattern)]
```

Is there a way to make this search faster? This works in a small dataframe but doesn't work if it's big (millions rows).

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: What is "*forever*"? How many items do you have in the list?

Comment: @mozway, there are 1000 items in that list. It takes me about 1 hour to run that code. There are 10 millions row at the moment.

Comment: You can sort the list with most frequent matches first to speed it up (assuming you have most rows that match). Any chance you can break the test on smaller groups to avoid testing all terms on all rows?

Comment: I don't have information on the most frequent matches to be honest. I could the dataframes to smaller chunks but will that help?

Comment: Only if you can use a different subset of words to match for each chunk, else no.

Comment: In that case, I can't chunk. Is this the most efficient way to search for the substring?

Comment: To me looks like it's as efficient as it's going to be unfortunately.. If `mylist` is short I don't if it would be faster to use a for loop (probably not though). This is a cpu bound task though so maybe look into multiprocessing (there are a couple modules that do this for pandas specifically but I can't remember their names.. Have a Google for pandas parallel or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


pattern = '|'.join(mylist)
def regex_filter(val):
    
    if val:
        mo = re.search(pattern,val)
        if mo:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return re.search(pattern,val)


frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['111,222,333,444', '11,44', '222,333,444','666,777','555']})
mylist = ['111', '222', '444','555']

frame[frame['a'].apply(regex_filter)]
```

Comment: For this small data frame, `frame['a'].apply(regex_filter)` is slower than the OP's `frame.a.str.contains(pattern)`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see if this might work (scale) for you.  Using a data frame with about 100K records and a mylist of about 400 entries I get these results.

**Original Code**

```
%%timeit
frame.a.str.contains(pattern)
620 ms ± 54.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Using explode and isin()**

```
%%timeit
frame['a'].str.split(',').explode().isin(mylist).groupby(level=0).max()
103 ms ± 2.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Data Generation Code for the Tests Above**

```
n = 333000
b = np.random.choice([False,True], size=n, p=[0.7,0.3])
s = pd.Series([str(np.random.randint(100,1000)) for i in range(n)])
mylist = pd.Series([str(np.random.randint(100,1000)) for i in range(550)]).unique()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': s, 'grp': b.cumsum()})
frame = df.groupby('grp').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x['a'])).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'a'})

len(frame)
99816

len(mylist)
418

pattern = '|'.join(mylist)
```